# Making an online Java game integrate with Facebook

Tags: java, facebook

I have an online Java game I'm working on, how would I go about making it so that it was able to "know" which facebook user was logged in and who their friends are? (It's sort of a social writing game and I want users to be able to choose which friends are allowed to edit the story)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your web page, have the facebook login button plugin to get people to log in.  Then you can grab their user id for friends using one of the SDKs (your choice...what ever is easiest to integrate into your java code) and then pass that info into your java app.